# передать action из формы через ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

как передать action в файл через ajax?

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/assets/ajax.php",
            dataType: "html",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
               alert(data);
            },
            error: function(data) { // Данные не отправлены
                $('body').append('<ul class="alert-data error"><li>Произошла ошибка. Повторите попытку или обратитесь в службу поддержки!</li></ul>');
            }
          });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('form').on('submit',function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var self = this;
       $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
               alert(data);
            },
            error: function(data) { // Данные не отправлены
                $('.message').html('');
                $('.message').append('<ul class="alert-data error"><li>Произошла ошибка. Не найден URL - '+ $(self).attr('action') +'! Обратитесь в службу поддержки!</li></ul>');
                $('.message').append('<ul class="alert-data error"><li>Данные из формы: '+ $(self).serialize() +'</li></ul>');
            }
          });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/assets/ajax.php" method="post" >
<input type="text" name="text"></input>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"></input>
<input type="submit"></input>
</form>
<div class="message"></div>
```