# Обращение к базе данных MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, база-данных

Собственно вопрос в том , как сделать обращение в баззу данных при помощи браузера.
Я знаю ,что это делается при помощи php (запросы в MySQL) и javascript(делаем поля редактируемыми) ну и собственно html (нарисовать какую-нибудь страницу для браузера) .

---

Но не могу найти подробных статей в интернете ,не могли бы вы помочь в этом?
Спасибо за внимание=)

Comment: Как вариант  - https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp или статья по созданию примитивного приложения на данной связке технологий - https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/os-php-jquery-ajax/index.html

Comment: Вот в этом [ответe](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/983046/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-action-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-ajax/983048#983048), пример (эмуляция) отправки данных из формы на сервер, средствами `ajax`

Comment: Лучше всего изучите работу с pdo -> http://phpfaq.ru/pdo , тогда этот вопрос отпадет сам по себе

Answer (score -1):

```
Подключение к БД (старое mysql):
mysql_connect($database_host, $database_user, $database_password);
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_select_db($database_name);

Подключение к БД (новое mysqli):
$connect = mysqli_connect($database_host, $database_user, $database_password, $database_name);
mysqli_query($connect, "SET NAMES utf8");
```

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php

Comment: Для информации: "старого mysql" уже давно не существует в природе